# How to dynamically inject token into lexer rule

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

Generally, I have a lexer file and a parser file, and I import lexer file into parser file.
My problem is I want to keep a rule called userdefinedValue in lexer file, it should be a set of String. But the value of it can only be sure when I run my program.  
So how to dynamical inject String into  userdefinedValue which is in lexer?

**Here is my lexer:**

```
lexer grammar TransitionLexer;

BOOLEAN: 'true' | 'false';
IF: 'if';
THEN: 'then';
ELSE: 'else';

UserdefinedValue: ;
NAME: (ALPHA | CHINESE | '_')(ALPHA | CHINESE | '_'|DIGIT)*;

ALPHA: [a-zA-Z];
CHINESE: [\u4e00-\u9fa5];

NUMBER: INT | REAL;
INT: DIGIT+
    |'(-'DIGIT+')';
REAL: DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT+)?
    | '(-' DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT+)? ')';
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];

OPCOMPARE: '='|'>='|'<='|'!='|'>'|'<';
WS: [ \t\n\r]+ ->skip;
SL_COMMENT:  '/*' .*? '*/' ->skip;
```

**And my parser:**

```
grammar TransitionCondition;
import TransitionLexer;

condition : stat+ EOF;
stat : single | expr;

single: pair EOF;

expr: pair (('and' | 'or') pair)+
    | '(' pair ')';

pair: '(' var OPCOMPARE value ')'   # keyValuePair
      | booleanExpr # booleanPair
      | BOOLEAN         # plainBooleanPair
      ;

var: localStates
     | globalStates
     | connector
     ;
localStates: NAME;
globalStates: 'Top' ('.' brick)+ '.' NAME;
connector: brick '.' NAME;

value: UserdefinedValue | basicValue;

basicValue: booleanExpr | arithmeticExpr;

booleanExpr: booleanExpr op=('and' | 'or') booleanExpr
                       | BOOLEAN
                       | relationExpr
                       | 'not' booleanExpr
                       | '(' booleanExpr ')'
                       ;
relationExpr: arithmeticExpr
                      | arithmeticExpr OPCOMPARE arithmeticExpr
                      ;
arithmeticExpr: arithmeticExpr op=('*'|'/') arithmeticExpr
                           | arithmeticExpr op=('+'|'-') arithmeticExpr
                           | NAME
                           | NUMBER
                           | '(' arithmeticExpr ')'
                           ;

brick: NAME;
```

### What I have tried

As you can see, the UserdefinedValue in lexer ie empty. And I read some answer of
other's question. such as [Dynamically create lexer rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008134/dynamically-create-lexer-rule)

So I alter my parser file partly like this:

```
grammar TransitionCondition;
import TransitionLexer;
@lexer :: header{
    import java.util.*;
}
@lexer :: members{
    Set<String> keywords;
    public TransitionConditionLexer(CharStream input, Set<String> keywords) {
         super(input);
         this.keywords = keywords;
     }
}

condition : stat+ EOF;
stat : single | expr;

single: pair EOF;

expr: pair (('and' | 'or') pair)+
    | '(' pair ')';

pair: '(' var OPCOMPARE value ')'   # keyValuePair
      | booleanExpr # booleanPair
      | BOOLEAN         # plainBooleanPair
      ;

var: localStates
     | globalStates
     | connector
     ;
localStates: NAME;
globalStates: 'Top' ('.' brick)+ '.' NAME;
connector: brick '.' NAME;

value:  basicValue {if(keywords.contains($text)) type=Keywords;};
fragment Keywords : ;
```

But it went wrong in java file. And I don't know what to do.

Comment: Why? All you need is the usual `primary : IDENTIFIER` rule.

Comment: But the IDENTIFIER can have many branches, and the value of them is uncertain until I run part of my main prog, so I need to inject them dynamically.

Comment: I added a v4 example in the other Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008134/dynamically-create-lexer-rule

Comment: Thanks very much!